# Httpclient consume web api via console app C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to consume the below web api via console app using Httpclient. I am stuck as in how to pass the parameter. The paramter is coming as a command line argument.
This is my Rest api

```
[HttpPost, Route("Test")]
        public IHttpActionResult Test(bool sample = false)
        {             
                return Ok();
        }
```

The parameter comes in this was as command line argument

```
/Parameters:sample=true.
```

Here is how I am parsing out the parameter in the console app

```
 static int Main(string[] args)
        {

                if (args.Length == 0)
                {
                    Console.Error.WriteLine("No action provided.");
                    return -1;
                }
                foreach (string param in args)
                {
                    switch (param.Substring(0, param.IndexOf(":")))
                    {
                        case "/Action":
                            action = param.Substring(param.IndexOf(":") + 1);
                            break;
                        case "/Parameters":
                            parameter = param.Substring(param.IndexOf(":") + 1);
                            break;    
                    }
                }
            return 0;
        }
```

Once I get my parameter which is in this format

parameter = "sample=true"

I am trying to invoke the web api call but unable to pass the parameter value. can anybody pin point what I am doing wrong

```
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("BaseWebApiUrl"));
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                    var apiUrl = GetApiURL();


                   var Context = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parameter), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

 var respFeed = await client.PostAsync(apiUrl, Context);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default in Web Api basic type parameters are never bound to the body of the request.

If you want to forcefully bind your `bool` parameter with the request body you need to decorate it with `FromBodyAttribute`:

```
[HttpPost, Route("Test")]
public IHttpActionResult Test([FromBody] bool sample = false)
{             
    return Ok();
}
```

**Be aware** that even if you do this your request is not valid for Web Api. A single basic type parameter must be passed with a specific format. In your case your request body must be the following:

```
=true
```

---

A better approach is to turn your Action parameter into a class:

```
public class TestModel
{
    public bool Sample { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost, Route("Test")]
public IHttpActionResult Test(TestModel model)
{
    return Ok();
}
```

This way you will be able to send a Json object as request body, like:

```
{
    "sample": true
}
```

This is a small example of how you could achieve such a result:

```
var parameterDictionary = parameter.Split("=").ToDictionary(s => s[0], s => bool.Parse(s[1]));
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parameterDictionary);
var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var respFeed = await client.PostAsync(apiUrl, content);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass it as a part of the url.

```
private void CallService(bool sample)
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("BaseWebApiUrl"));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    var apiUrl = $"http://yourserver:port/api/somecontroller/?sample={sample}";

    var Context = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parameter), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    var respFeed = await client.PostAsync(apiUrl, Context);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, change your method signature to

```
public IHttpActionResult Test([FromBody]bool sample = false)
```

since primitive types are resolved from URL/Query String and not body. By adding FromBody attribute will force it to resolve from the body.

Next, since you said you have parameter value as var parameter = "sample=true";,  change your parameter construction to

```
var jsonParam = new { sample = parameter.split('=')[1]}; // I'm leaving null checks and validation for simplicity
var Context = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonParam), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```